# Import of TXT file to MySQL - error due to '\' and '/' contained in import file

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a series of large files and due to every row of data having the following characters

`\` and `/`

each row fails when I import it into mysql (even if I ignore errors).  Is there a function I can use to fix this? (happy as well to replace with another character upon import).

I could of course manually prep the file prior to import - but that is impractical.  Thank you.

Comment: How are you doing the import?

Comment: Can you show some lines from the file?

Comment: I am doing the import using toad's UI (so I don't have actual code). Sample rows are:

Comment: Sample rows are (first row is header row):     
CIK Company Name Form Type Date Filed Filename
1000045 NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC 4 20120706 edgar/data/1000045/0001000045-12-000006.txt
1000045 NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC 8-K 20120706 edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-12-295733.txt
1000191 RIVERSOURCE VARIABLE ACCOUNT 10 485BPOS 20120706 edgar/data/1000191/0000950123-12-009856.txt
1000191 RIVERSOURCE VARIABLE ACCOUNT 10 485BPOS 20120706 edgar/data/1000191/0000950123-12-009856.txt
1000275 ROYAL BANK OF CANADA FWP 20120706 edgar/data/1000275/0001214659-12-002969.txt
Thank you

Comment: You may add this text into the question.

Comment: There are should be exact field and line dilimiters. In your case whitespace is used as field separator, and also it is used in field values, e.g. - 'ROYAL BANK OF CANADA'.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example with [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command -

File 'cik.csv':

```
1000275;"ROYAL BANK OF CANADA";FWP;20120706;edgar/data/1000275/0001214659-12-002969.txt
1000276;"ROYAL BANK OF CANADA";FWP;20120706;edgar/data/1000275/0001214659-12-002969.txt
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE cik(
  CIK INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  Company VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  Form VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  Filename VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Import command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'cik.csv' INTO TABLE cik
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Also, you can use Data Import tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).